# Example is not working in Kendo UI Dojo, but is working on my host

Tags: json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have created my first Kendo grid example with a restfull webservice that's returning json.  If I run my example in Kendo UI Dojo the grid doesn't show my data that's returned.  The service is returning data (checked with Fiddler).  If I deploy the same code to my host and run it over there everything is fine.  But I want my example working from the Dojo so it's easier to play with some attributes/properties and I don't have to upload it to my host every time.

```
<body>
  <div id="grid"></div>
  <script>
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        sortable  : true,
        groupable : true,
        scrollable: true,
        height    : "300px",
        pageable  : {
            pageSizes: 9
        },
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url     : "http://www.***.be/kris/socadKurt/Services/SocadLight.svc/GetVelden",
                    dataType: "Json"
                }
            }
        },
        columns   : [

            { field: "CampusId", title: "CampusId" },
            { field: "Omschrijving", title: "Omschrijving" }
        ]
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Try sharing the link to where you have the code in the dojo so we can help you debugging it.

Comment: Did you added the references for Kendo UI correctly in the dojo ?

Comment: Here is the link for debugging it in the Dojo
http://dojo.telerik.com/ExuWA

@AmalDev I have used the default references who are automatically added in the Dojo.  I used the same in the dojo as with my host.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is happening due to this error and this happens when your host and originator of the request is different.

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://runner.telerik.io' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Please go through the following links to know more about it

[Unleash your AJAX requests with CORS](http://dev.housetrip.com/2014/04/17/unleash-your-ajax-requests-with-cors/)

[Fetch data From Another Domain by using CORS with All (Modern) Browsers](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/datasource/cors)

Comment: Reading through those 2 links and being a noob, let's me understand that I have to adapt my rest service? Is this assumption correct?
Do I really have to change my service for only having the advance to test and play around in the dojo.  In the production environment my service and kendo are on the same host.

Comment: You have two options, one is to use jsop as the data type, or you need to set up in server so that it allows cross origin requests

Comment: I changed the datatype from json to jsonp without succes.  You can see the code here.
http://dojo.telerik.com/ExuWA/6

Comment: if you change the datatype, then your service also needs to modified so that it can handle jsonp datatype

Comment: Ok, so I always have to change my service to test this in the dojo. Isn't there a way it can be accomplished without changing my service?
As I understand it's better/faster to use json, but that CORS thing to solve the issue it's hard to understand the solution.  I understand what the problem is, but I think I have to read the 2 documents again.

Comment: So both solution (jsonp or CORS) needs a change in the service?  It can't be done without a change in the service. So I better go for the CORS solution because json is better as jsonp?  I have to read the 2 links again because I understand the problem of different hosts but the CORS solution is hard to understand for a noob as me...